# Remove an item from the Start menu using batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to remove an item from the start menu using batch scripts in admin mode ofcourse
I tried the following

```
Set scut=C:\users
del /s /q /f %scut%\name of shortcut.lnk
```

but it does not seem to be working. can anyone please point me to the right direction.

I will make the question a bit clear by providing screen shot 
[image]
here actually I want to remove Notepad or Microsoft Word 2010 or notepad++.exe using command prompt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I got your question right...

If you want to delete a shortcut from the windows start menu you must know where the .lnk files are located:

Per-user menu: C:\Users[username]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu
All user's menu: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu

So the code should be something link this:

```
DEL /Q "C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\shortcut.lnk"
```

or

```
DEL /Q "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\shortcut.lnk"
```

If the .lnk is located in a subfolder you'll obviously have to modify the path ;-)

Comment: I tried finding the Notepad or Microsoft Word 2010 or notepad++.exe in the folder C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\  but it consist of system tools, control panel , my computer . I was not able to find any shortcuts for items on the left part of the start menu :(

Comment: Thanks i found in the pinned section of the Start Menu "C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned" and I am able to remove. But it is still visible in the start menu . When I click it says"File not found Do u want to delete it" . But I need to clear the start menu also and after removing the shortcut from the mentioned directory the icon should also get removed from the start menu.

Answer (score 0):

```
Set scut=C:\Users
cd /d %scut%
del /s /q /f "name of shortcut.lnk"
```

So, change directory to `%scut%` and recursively delete the shortcut in double quotes (because spaces).

Try http://superuser.com next time, it's more IT Pro audience oriented.

EDIT. Apparently `del` doesn't follow SYMLINKS, so `"%scut%\All Users\"` becomes a particular case, just add it at the end.

```
cd /d "%scut%\All Users"
del /s /q /f "name of shortcut.lnk"
```